# how to delete all images from folder on single click in asp.net mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to delete all images from single click from view.My images are in the uploads folder in my project directory.I tried following code but it is not working please show me the correct way of doing this

Here is my controller method

```
    public bool Delete()
    {
        try
        {
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"~/Uploads/{0}", "*.jpg,*.png");
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(file);
                }

            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }


    }
```

Here is my button from view

```
    <input type="button" value="Delete" id="deleteBtn" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Here is my javascript

```
$("#deleteBtn").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Delete", "Document")",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',

            })
});
```

Comment: What is not working? What errors are you getting? (and as side note, delete the pointless `contentType` and `data` options)

Comment: i am getting exception like 'Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\uploads' on button click

Comment: Where are your files located? You should be using `Server.MapPath` to get the virtual path

Comment: my files are the 'uploads' folder

Comment: The to get the path, use `var path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads");`